# How to create a query to group by date order with specific value

Tags: sql, graph

[image: 1]

I have this table and want to write a query and to display data as chart where for each day to display how many orders where under 50, under 100, under 250.

Can you help me how to create the graph?

This is the query I have written:

```
SELECT 
    o_id,
    DATE(invoice_date) AS __timestamp,
    SUM(if(amount_sale < 50,amount_sale,0)) AS `s50`,
    SUM(if(amount_sale > 50 && amount_sale < 100,amount_sale,0)) AS `s100`,
    SUM(if(amount_sale > 100 && amount_sale < 250,amount_sale,0)) AS `s250`,
    SUM(if(amount_sale > 250 && amount_sale < 500,amount_sale,0)) AS `s500`,
    SUM(if(amount_sale > 500 && amount_sale < 1000,amount_sale,0)) AS `s1000`,
    SUM(if(amount_sale > 1000 && amount_sale < 2500,amount_sale,0)) AS `s2500`,
    SUM(if(amount_sale > 2500,amount_sale,0)) AS `over_2500`
FROM
    (SELECT 
         o.id as o_id,
         o.ref,
         o.invoice_date,
         SUM(CASE
                 WHEN op.was_in_promo = 1 
                     THEN op.quantity * (op.promo_price +opt.promo_amount)
                     ELSE op.quantity * (op.price +opt.amount)
             END) AS amount_sale
     FROM
         thelia.order o
     LEFT JOIN
         order_product op ON op.order_id = o.id
     LEFT JOIN
         order_product_tax opt ON opt.order_product_id = op.id
     LEFT JOIN 
         order_status os on os.id = o.status_id
     LEFT JOIN
         module_i18n mi ON mi.id = o.payment_module_id
                        AND mi.locale="de_DE"
     WHERE
         o.status_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16)
         AND (`o`.`created_at` > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 Year))
     GROUP BY
         o.id) AS expr_qry
GROUP BY
    o_id
LIMIT 50000;
```

Comment: tag your database

Comment: ans also what's your question? your query doesn't work? or do you get an error? aslo provide sample data